# Evaluate integral $\int\int xe^{xy} dx dy$, strange result after rearranging

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have to compute the following integral
$$
 \int_{-1}^0 \int_0^1 x\cdot e^{xy} dx dy
$$
It exists according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E0%20%5Cint_0%5E1%20x%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7Bxy%7D%20dx%20dy). Now I want to evaluate it, let $\varepsilon > 0$, then
\begin{align*}
 \int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \int_0^1 x\cdot e^{xy} dx dy 
= \int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{y^2} \left( \int_0^y t\cdot e^t dt \right) dy
\end{align*}
by the substitution rule. Further
$$
 \int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{y^2} \left( \int_0^y t\cdot e^t dt \right) dy
  = \int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{y^2} (y-1)e^y dy
$$
and here is the problem, the integral
$$
 \int_{-1}^0 \frac{y-1}{y^2} e^y dy
$$
does not converges anymore, according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%28-1%29%5E0%20%28y-1%29%2Fy%5E2%20e%5Ey%20dy).

1) What went wrong here?

2) How to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
 \int_{-1}^0 \int_0^1 x\cdot e^{xy} dx dy=\int_0^1\int_{-1}^0 x\cdot e^{xy} dydx=\int_0^1\left[e^{xy}\right]_{y=-1}^{0}dx=\int_0^11-e^{-x}dx=$$$$=1+(e^{-1}-1)=e^{-1}\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you also see why my way (first $x$, then $y$) gives a nonsense result? Because I am wondering in mathematics several ways should lead to the same result if done correctly...

Comment: @Stefan: You did a mistake in this computation$$\int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{y^2} \left( \int_0^y t\cdot e^t dt \right) dy
  = \int_{-1}^{\varepsilon} \frac{1}{y^2} (\color{red}{1+}(y-1)e^y) dy\ .$$